# How do I display a bootstrap modal in my case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap and I have a link that redirects to `images#show` action from `home#index`. The link is written in haml:

```
- url = @entry.class.to_s.downcase.singularize
    = link_to(send("#{url}_path", @entry), data: { 'type' => @entry.class.to_s.downcase }) do
        = yield
```

So currently, the `home#index` displays a list of images  and when an image is clicked on, the link written above redirects the user to the view for the specific image  Ex:  `images/1`. That is to say that `@entry` represents the image and when clicked redirects to the specific image or (`@entry`).

I do not want to move away from the homepage (`home#index`), I just want to display a modal view that will take into account which images ( or `@entry`) was clicked on. How do I modify this link and add code that will display a bootstrap modal when the above link is clicked on ? What other steps should I follow ? I just need help to the point of displaying the modal.

Here is my trace:

```
Started GET "/images/3" for ::1 at 2016-09-07 22:28:10 -0400
 Processing by ImagesController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1      ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Image Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Group Load (0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "groups".* FROM "groups" INNER JOIN     "group_memberships" ON "groups"."id" = "group_memberships"."group_id" WHERE     "group_memberships"."member_id" = $1 AND "group_memberships"."member_type" = $2     AND "group_memberships"."group_type" = $3  [["member_id", 1], ["member_type", "User"], ["group_type", "Group"]]
  GroupMembership Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "group_memberships".* FROM "group_memberships" WHERE "group_memberships"."member_id" = $1 AND "group_memberships"."member_type" = $2  [["member_id", 3], ["member_type", "Image"]]
  GroupMembership Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "group_memberships".* FROM "group_memberships" WHERE "group_memberships"."group_type" = $1 AND "group_memberships"."member_type" = $2 AND "group_memberships"."member_id" = $3    AND "group_memberships"."group_id" IN (-1, -1)  [["group_type", "Group"],   ["member_type", "User"], ["member_id", 1]]
  Rendered images/_modal.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered images/show.js.erb (1.2ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 10.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a `js` template and change your links to use use the `remote: true` option:

```
<%- @images.each do |image| -%>
<%= link_to '...', image_path(image) remote: true %>
<%- end -%>
<div id="modals"></div>
```

Next in the controller the response type can be set to `js` (probably a good idea to also keep the `html` option around):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Then in the template that handles the `js`:

```
// app/views/images/show.js.erb
$("#modals").html('<%= j render "images/modal", image: @image %>');
$('#modals .modal').modal();
$('#modals .modal').modal('.toggle');
```

Finally add a partial for the modal and setup any markup needed:

```
<!-- app/views/images/_modal.html.erb -->
<div class="modal fade">
  ...
  <%= image_tag(image.url, class: "img-responsive") %>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion. It looks great behind the scenes but still the modal does not show. I added the trace to the question doe you to see.

Comment: Maybe the mistake is coming from me using both html.erb and haml.erb in the app.

Comment: I need your help. I am stuck on using Javascript on the modal contents. Here is the question I posted. I have tried a lot but it seems there is something I am missing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39442258/how-do-i-hide-and-show-the-contents-contents-of-a-modal

Comment: I implemented your method and it works . Now I am having trouble using Javascript to manipulate the contents of the modal. 
Here is a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565102/how-to-use-javascript-to-manipulate-modal-content