# How do I hide and show the contents contents of a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

In my modal, I have a link. The link is written as follows:

```
<%= link_to "HIDE DETAILS", '#', class:'right' %>
```

When I click on that link, I want the link to display "SHOW DETAILS" instead of "HIDE DETAILS" and the div with id= "details" should disappear off the view with all its children. And when the link is clicked again, the link shows "HIDE DETAILS" and the contents of the div with details to show and vice-versa (toggle functionality).
And when the page is first displayed, I want the div with details and all its content to initially not show and the link should display "SHOW DETAILS". How do I write the Javascript to do this ? It must be really simple.

Here is the div:

```
<div id="details">
   <ul class="errors"></ul>
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:0.5em; color: #860038"><i>media type:      </i></div><%= @image.media_type %>
   <br>
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:0.5em; color: #860038"><i>subject:   </i></div> <%= @image.subject %>
   <br>
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:0.5em; color: #860038"><i>title: </i></div> <%= @image.title %>
   <br>
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:0.5em; color: #860038"><i>full description: </i></div>
   <%= @image.description %>
   <br>
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:0.5em; color:#860038;"><i>location: </i></div>
   <%= @image.location %>
   <br>
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:0.5em; color: #860038;"><i>date: </i>  </div>
   <br>
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:0.5em; color: #860038;"><i>author: </i></div>
   <%= @image.author %>
   <br>
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:0.5em; color: #860038;"><i>source: </i></div>
   <%= @image.source %>
   <br>
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:0.5em; color:#860038;"><i>tags: </i>   </div> <%= @image.tag_list.join(' - ') %>
   <br>
   <br>
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:0.5em; color:#009345;">This item is shared by</div><span style="color:#0F004E;"><%= @image.user.name_first+ ' ' %>    </span><span style="color:#860038;"><%=@image.user.name_last %><br><br>
   <%= link_to "Edit Item", '#', class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary"  %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple..just use [Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

example:-

```
//erb code
<h1 id="title">Toggle div onclick</h1>

<a class="right" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Toggle me">
  <span id="toggle-text">SHOW</span> DETAILS
</a>
<div id="details" style="display:none;">


//js code
$('.right').on("click", function() {
  //toggle the div
  $("#details").toggle();
  //update the text too
  if ($("span#toggle-text").html() == "SHOW") {
    $("span#toggle-text").html("HIDE");
  } else {
    $("span#toggle-text").html("SHOW");
  }
});
```

**CHECK [THIS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MilindSingh84/856q24ox/1/)**

Comment: What about the link text ?

Comment: Thanks, also this html is inside a jquery modal and as of now it s not working.

Comment: check the jquery...debug it using alert and check the id/class selector that you are using to trigger...

Comment: I have added js fiddle...check that out...and let me know..@MoussaSarr

Answer (score 1):

Try this HTML:

```
      <button id="myButton"> Click</button>
      <div id="myDiv">Hello</div>
```

And this JS:

```
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
            $("#myDiv").toggle();
    });
```

To have it initially hidden, use this css:

```
<style>

    #myDiv{
        display: none;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Your implementation is not specific to my case. How about the showing and hiding of the text displayed as the link ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want more specific answer.

Given:

```
<%= link_to "HIDE DETAILS", '#', class:'right' %>
```

Try:

```
$('.right').click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  $link = $(this);
  $detail = $('#details'); 
  if ($link.text() == "SHOW DETAILS") {
    $link.text("HIDE DETAILS");
  } else {
    $link.text("SHOW DETAILS");
  }
  $detail.toggle();   
}
```

**UPDATED**: If the links are in modal then you need to attach event listener dynamically, something like this:

```
$.fn.attachToggle = function() {
    $(this).click(function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $link = $(this);
      $detail = $('#details'); 
      if ($link.text() == "SHOW DETAILS") {
        $link.text("HIDE DETAILS");
      } else {
        $link.text("SHOW DETAILS");
      }
      $detail.toggle();   
    }
}
```

Then call `attachToggle` on modal body eg: `$([modal_body_id]).find('.right').attachToggle();`

Comment: detail is an id not a class . $detail = $("#detail) isn't it ?

Comment: Maybe it s because all this content is inside a bootstrap -modal but it s not working yet

Comment: hiya, updated my answer based on your comment, see if it helps you

Comment: So if the modal body has an id of modalBodyId, I should call attchToggle on body like this $("#modalBodyId").find('.right').attachToggle();   Right?

Comment: Yea, says if the modal is hidden initially, call attachToggle() right after showing it

Comment: It is still not working. I reposted the question with more details here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565102/how-to-use-javascript-to-manipulate-modal-content

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, instead of using the link_to rails helper, use a simple link element, since you won't need to go to a rails view you don't need the rails helper, but in case you need it, just use ERB:

```
<a href="{%= view_path %}">Go!</a>
```

Now, in your case, you just need to use jQuery to:

1. Change the link text (toggle the text)
2. Show/hide your content details

You can do something like this to do it, very simple:

```js
$("#theLink").click(function() {
  var link = $(this);
  var content = $('.details');
  
  if (link.text() === 'Show Details') {
    link.text('Hide Details');
    content.css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    link.text('Show Details');
    content.css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700; 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: peru;
}

.details {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="theLink">Show Details</a>
<div class="details">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi fugit iusto consequuntur distinctio omnis sint similique provident. Assumenda, est? Cumque inventore blanditiis officia corrupti voluptate qui quasi quae recusandae accusamus.
</div>
```

Comment: not working. So i reposted the question with more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565102/how-to-use-javascript-to-manipulate-modal-content