# How to use Javascript to manipulate modal content?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modals and Ruby on Rails. I was able to display the modal fine but I am having trouble using Javascript to manipulate the contents of the modal. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I was not able to use Javascript to impact the contents of the modal at all, to the point that I started wondering if there are such a thing as different stack levels on the DOM elements or whether even the modal contents are part of the DOM.

Here is my **app/views/home/index.haml:**

```
- url = @entry.class.to_s.downcase.singularize
= link_to(send("#{url}_path", @entry), remote: true) do
  = yield
#modals
```

The view contains the link to open up the modal and in this case @entry represents an image object. And in the **images controller** we have the show action, which I am using to display the modal:

```
def show
  authorize! :view, @image
  @can_destroy = can?('delete_asset', @image)
  @can_edit = can?('edit_metadata', @image)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And for the modal views, I have the **app/view/show.js.erb**

```
$("#modals").html('<%= j render "images/modal", image: @image %>');
$('#modals .modal').modal();
$('#modals .modal').modal('.toggle');
```

And finally, I have the modal partial in app/views/images/_modal.haml

```
.modal
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
      = image_tag(@image.file_original.url(:modal))
      .modal-body
        #shortdesc.row
          .col-md-6
            short description: #{@image.description_short}
          .col-md-6.rightButton
            %a.detailers
              %span#toggle-text SHOW
              DETAILS
        %ul.errors
        #detail.details{:style => "display: none"}
          %div.modal-details
            %i media type:
          = @image.media_type
          %br/
          %div.modal-details
            %i subject:
          = @image.subject
          %br/
          %div.modal-details
            %i title:
          = @image.title
          %br/
          %div.modal-details
            %i full description:
          = @image.description
          %br/
          %div.modal-details
            %i location:
          = @image.location
          %br/
          %div.modal-details
            %i date:
          %br/
          %div.modal-details
            %i author:
          = @image.author
          %br/
          %div.modal-details
            %i source:
          = @image.source
          %br/
          %div.modal-details
            %i tags:
          = @image.tag_list.join(' - ')
          %br/
          %br/
          %div.modal-detailsgreen This item is shared by
          %span.sharedbyfirstname
            = @image.user.name_first
          %span.sharedbylastname
            = @image.user.name_last
            %br/
            %br/
```

Now I want to hide and show (toggle) the contents of the div with id= "detail" and class ="details" when the link with class= "detailers" is clicked on. I have tried to write Javascript inside the show.js.erb to manipulate the contents of the modal with no success. Is there a certain place I should put my JS to manipulate the  contents of the JS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#modals .modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  // do something… 
});
```

Comment: So first should I use that on show.js.erb or on home.js ? Second, How would you select the link with class ".detailer". Would you use $(' #modals .modal' a .detailer ) ? Can you detail your answer and at least specifying where you would write that and how you would select the link with class .detailers ?

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".